# Eloquent ORM, when ID lives within the initial table, not the reference table

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to figure out how to use the Eloquent ORM to ask for records from the `addresses` table when my schema looks like this:

```
TABLE users {
id
billing_addr_id
shipping_addr_id
}

TABLE addresses {
id
address1
address2
city
state
zip
country
}
```

As you can see, I want to extract a record for `billing_addr_id` and `shipping_addr_id`, but the `address` table doesn't have a reference to the user, simply because not all addresses will be connected to `users`.

I hope this makes sense!

Comment: Why would you have an address not linked to a user?

Comment: Because it's not just a user that needs an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your Eloquent models first.

You can do something like (not tested)...

```
<?php
//app/models/address.php
class Address extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = "addresses";

  public function users() {
    return $this->belongsTo('users', 'billing_addr_id', 'shipping_addr_id');
  }
}

//app/models/user.php
class User extends Eloquent {
  protected $table = "users";

  public function address($type = "billing") {
      return Address::where("id", ($type == "billing") ? $this->billing_addr_id : $this->shipping_addr_id);
  }
}

// test the model
$user = User::find(123);
$billingAddress = $user->address("billing")->pluck('address1');
$shippingAddress = $user->address("shipping")->pluck('address1');

var_dump($billingAddress, $shippingAddress);
```

Comment: Well, this has the call asking for the address itself ... I will never ask for the address directly, but rather ask for the user and want the addresses connected.

Comment: Omitted it on purpose - so that you can use it as you need. You may be interested in using `->first()` so that you can simply do `->first()->address1` or more easily `->pluck('address1')` - your preference.

Comment: Fair enough! Thanks a ton, Rob.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot you dont have a user_id on the address table...then I would do it like this...

```
 class User extends Eloquent {
   protected $table = "users";

   public function bill_to(){
     return Address::where('id','=',$this->billing_addr_id)->first();
   }

   public function ship_to(){
    return Address::where('id','=',$this->shipping_addr_id)->first();
   }

 }
```

THen you call in your logic...

```
 $user = User::find(2);
 $address = $user->bill_to();
```

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'addresses.billing_addr_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `addresses` where `addresses`.`billing_addr_id` in (?, ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '1', 1 => '33', ))

Comment: This could also work. I prefer @Rob W method. Thanks for taking the time! :)